# Sql Timeout in MS Test when running tests in Parallel

Tags: c#, sql, automation, mstest

I have framework which runs 12 threads parallel - each will have different test but may have to get result from sql connection

Doing so - I'm receiving below error - Is there a way where I can do any workaround in my code to make it work without loosing parallel threads

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding..

My Config:

Code:

```
private static void ExecuteQuery(TestConfigurationCDO testConfiguration, string query)
{
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(testConfiguration.ConnectionString))
{
var orderTable = sqlConnection.ExecuteQuery(query);
}
}


//Execution
public static DataTable ExecuteQuery(this SqlConnection sqlConnection, string queryString)
{
if (sqlConnection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sqlConnection));

DataSet dataset;
try
{
//Checking the state of the connection
if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed ||
sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
sqlConnection.Open();

SqlDataAdapter dataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter
{
SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, sqlConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.Text }
};

dataset = new DataSet();
dataAdaptor.Fill(dataset, "table");
sqlConnection.Close();
return dataset.Tables["table"];
}
catch (Exception e)
{
dataset = null;
sqlConnection.Close();
Console.WriteLine("ERROR {0}", e);
//LogHelpers.Write("ERROR :: " + e.Message);
return null;
}
finally
{
sqlConnection.Close();
dataset = null;
}
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of your tests - can you make do with selecting fewer rows from each table, e.g. make all your queries TOP(1)?

Comment: Purpose is only like either deleting, or selecting or updating values - IN select statement it may need * but for rest it performs action on one record only

Comment: There are two possibilities to my mind 1) you are exhausting the underlying connection pool, 2) you have a SQL deadlock - either could surface as timeouts. To check option 1, try increasing the CommandTimeout when you create SqlCommands and see if there is a point at which the entire testsuite will complete, or alternatively reduce the number of threads to see if that help. For option 2) you'll need to profile the database or run queries to check for deadlocks

Comment: Yes I can try on setting timeouts at connection string and in command

Comment: Well I guess it's failing a performance / scalability test here.

Comment: I tried adding command timeout but no luck it still giving timeout error!

--- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand

Comment: maybe i think I should use with (nolock) - as few tests using the same query